# Weird "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error while using Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to run my test however the I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". Any thoughts? I am using Moq.

Test Method:

```
     // Arrange
    Mock<ICustomerRepository> CustomerRepo = new Mock<ICustomerRepository>();
    Customer NewCustomer = new Customert() { ID = 123456789, Date = DateTime.Now };
    CustomerRepo.Setup(x => x.Add()).Returns(NewCustomer);
    var Controller = new CustomerController(CustomerRepo.Object, new Mock<IProductRepository>().Object);

    // Act
    IHttpActionResult actionResult = Controller.CreateCustomer();
```

CreateCustomer Method:

```
     Customer NewCustomer = CustomerRepository.Add();

      //ERROR OCCURS BELOW  
     return Created(Request.RequestUri + "/" + NewCustomer.ID.ToString(), new { customerID = NewCustomer.ID });
```

Comment: When you debug, which object is null?  Have you set up your Request object?

Comment: The NewCustomer object in the creatcustomer method is populated with the ID and date set in the testmethod

Comment: And NewCustomer and Request are not null if you run your test in debug mode?  When using Moq you need to configure your HttpContext, including your Request object.

Comment: NewCustomer is not null, Request is null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you set up Moq, you need to additionally configure your HttpContext, otherwise your Request will be null.  You can set it up in a function in your controller that you call at the beginning of your test case, something like:

```
private Mock<ControllerContext> GetContextBase()
{
    var fakeHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
    var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
    var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
    var session = new MockHttpSession();
    var server = new MockServer();
    var parms = new RequestParams();
    var uri = new Uri("http://TestURL/Home/Index");

    var fakeIdentity = new GenericIdentity("DOMAIN\\username");
    var principal = new GenericPrincipal(fakeIdentity, null);

    request.Setup(t => t.Params).Returns(parms);
    request.Setup(t => t.Url).Returns(uri);
    fakeHttpContext.Setup(t => t.User).Returns(principal);
    fakeHttpContext.Setup(ctx => ctx.Request).Returns(request.Object);
    fakeHttpContext.Setup(ctx => ctx.Response).Returns(response.Object);
    fakeHttpContext.Setup(ctx => ctx.Session).Returns(session);
    fakeHttpContext.Setup(ctx => ctx.Server).Returns(server);

    var controllerContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
    controllerContext.Setup(t => t.HttpContext).Returns(fakeHttpContext.Object);

    return controllerContext;
}
```

The supporting classes are along the lines of:

```
/// <summary>
/// A Class to allow simulation of SessionObject
/// </summary>
public class MockHttpSession : HttpSessionStateBase
{
    Dictionary<string, object> m_SessionStorage = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public override object this[string name]
    {
        get {
            try
            {
                return m_SessionStorage[name];
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        set { m_SessionStorage[name] = value; }
    }

}

public class RequestParams : System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection
{
    Dictionary<string, string> m_SessionStorage = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public override void Add(string name, string value)
    {
        m_SessionStorage.Add(name, value);
    }

    public override string Get(string name)
    {
        return m_SessionStorage[name];
    }

}

public class MockServer : HttpServerUtilityBase
{
    public override string MapPath(string path)
    {

        return @"C:\YourCodePathTowherever\" + path;
    }
}
```

Lastly, in the top of your Test method, just add this call:

```
// Arrange
HomeController controller = new HomeController();
controller.ControllerContext = GetContextBase().Object;
```

That will give you a Request object to work with :)

[edit]

Name spaces you'll need are:

```
using System.Security.Principal;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Moq;
```

Comment: Thx. Could you state the namespaces required?

Comment: thx again. one last thing: i get this error "unrecognized escape sequence" on line var fakeIdentity = new GenericIdentity("DOMAIN\username");

Comment: I took out my test user name, you should include your own with double backslash escape in the domain\\username.  I edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Setting type as Mock on mock's declaration was causing me problems.

```cs
Mock<ICustomerRepository> CustomerRepo = new Mock<ICustomerRepository>();
```

Once you remove as follows might avoid this issue

```cs
var CustomerRepo = new Mock<ICustomerRepository>();
```